# unity3d выполнение скрипта по времени

Tags: c#, unity3d

У объекта должна меняться прозрачность, секунд на десять, а потом возвращаться в исходное состояние. Придумал вот такое:

```
public SpriteRenderer _sprite; 

public void Invisibility () 
{

    var color = _sprite.color;
    color.a = 0.4f;
    _sprite.color = color;
    StartCoroutine(Timer());
}
IEnumerator Timer() {
    var color = _sprite.color;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    color.a = 1;
    _sprite.color = color;
}
```

Но мне кажется, это не есть хорошо.

Comment: Ну а чем не нравится лично вам? Объяснили бы) А так..ну вполне себе подход, отчего же, имеет право на жизнь...Чуть только можно слегка подредактировать, убрав `color` в объявленную переменную что бы не писать `var color = _sprite.color;` ну в функции `Timer()` в конце написать `StopCoroutine("Timer")` [Наглядно](http://s017.radikal.ru/i402/1601/9b/44b8e5e09ee1.jpg) .... А в целом..Да вроде ничего страшного

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский видимо вот этого редактирования мне и не хватало. Спасибо.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: А не проще сделать анимацию которая будет менять альфа канал? Не придется ни строчки кода писать и вносить изменения в мерцание будет проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тот подход, который вы используете - вполне нормальный и имеет право на жизнь.

Если бы был код на страницу, то, возможно, можно было бы что-то исправить.

А данный код можно лишь слегка подредактировать, убрав `color` в объявленную переменную что бы не писать `var color = _sprite.color;` и в функции `Timer()` в конце написать `StopCoroutine("Timer")`

Пример:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnumeratorTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public SpriteRenderer _sprite;
    private Color _spriteColor;

    void Start() {
        _sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        _spriteColor = _sprite.color;
    }

    public void Invisibility () {        
        _spriteColor.a = 0.4f;
        _sprite.color = _spriteColor;
        StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    IEnumerator Timer() {        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        _spriteColor.a = 1;
        _sprite.color = _spriteColor;
        StopCoroutine ("Timer");
    }
}
```

Если еще больше оптимизировать, то можно сделать просто отдельную мааааааленьку функцию, которую можно использовать для изменения альфа канала. Вот как это в целом будет выглядеть:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnumeratorTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public SpriteRenderer _sprite;

    void Start() {
        _sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    public void Invisibility () {
        SetOpacity(_sprite, 0.4f);
        StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    IEnumerator Timer() {        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        SetOpacity(_sprite, 1);
        StopCoroutine ("Timer");
    }


    private void SetOpacity(SpriteRenderer sprite, float opacity) {
        sprite.color = new Color(sprite.color.r, sprite.color.g, sprite.color.b, opacity);
    }
}
```

Ну и конечно не забывать, что лучше не применять такие магические числа из головы как `0.4f`, а описать их как объявленную переменную и подставить её в в функцию.

А в целом ваш код - код как код.